# SQL Loop and update table with sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following shiftdate table that stores the amount of hours worked at rate1 and rate2 (these are stored in another table). I want to use this data to update the shiftdateTotal field with the total value. Hoping you can help?

SHIFTDATE Table

- shiftdateID int
- hourlyRate1ID int
- hoursRate1 int
- hourlyRate2ID int
- hoursRate2 int
- shiftDateTotal decimal

LISTITEM Table

- ListitemID int
- description string
- rateOfPay decimal

Example listItem row (23, BankHolidayRate, 12.50)

I'm able to create a SQL select that does the required calculation, see below:

```
    SELECT shiftDateID,
    hoursRate1, t2.rateOfPay as rate1,
    hoursRate2, t3.rateOfPay as rate2,
    (hoursRate1 * t2.rateOfPay) +  ([hoursRate2] * t3.rateOfPay) as myTotal
    from dbo.ShiftDate t1 

    inner join dbo.ListItem t2
    on t1.hourlyRate1ID = t2.listItemID

    inner join dbo.ListItem t3
    on t1.hourlyRate2ID = t3.listItemID
```

But now i'm a bit lost.. Using this query or something similar how can I insert the myTotal value into the shiftDateTotal for the required shiftdateID row?

Can i store this into a temp table, then loop through the data and update the SHIFTDATE table with myTotal?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just turn this into an update.  The transformation is pretty direct:

```
update sd
    set shiftDateTotal = (sd2.hoursRate1 * li1.rateOfPay) + (sd2.hoursRate2 * li2.rateOfPay) 
from dbo.ShiftDate sd inner join
     dbo.ListItem li1
     on sd.hourlyRate1ID = li1.listItemID inner join
     dbo.ListItem li2
     on sd.hourlyRate2ID = li2.listItemID;
```

Notes:

- I replaced the meaningless table aliases (`t1`, `t2`, `t3`) with more meaningful ones (abbreviations for the table names).
- I qualified all column names.
- You might want to be careful, in case any of the rate ids are `NULL`/missing in the original table.  In that case, you will want `left join`s and `coalesce()`s.

Comment: beat me to it :(